# How to add both back arrow and search view in Toolbar in android?

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am wondering how to add a back button as well as search view in Toolbar. I found for some answers but the problem is the code is adding either of the one and not the both.
[image]

I am looking for something like the one in above picture. And here is my code for back arrow but I also want to add a search view here.
How to do this?

```
            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:title="Subject Name"
            app:titleTextColor="#fff"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back_arrow"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">




        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't tag questions with IDE tags (android-studio) just because you use that IDE: these tags should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags), and the [tagging guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Also, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try it its a easy way just make toolbar and add what you need inside it. it will work like a LinearLayout**

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00adbd"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/tollbar_back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="BMI Calculator"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_info"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_info_outline_black_24dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>``
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these inside Activity `onCreate()`?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: Yup!, I have them

Answer (score 0):

In your activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

This will set the back arrow

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Create a menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Set the menu on toolbar

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search People");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    searchView.setIconified(false);

    return true;
}
```